# How to convert a floating-point number to a fixed-width string?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, rounding

I tried to find this question answered, but I haven't found anything related.

I have a variable that can be in a format like `50000.45` or in a format like `0.01`.

I need to write this variable in a label that is 4 digits wide.

What is the best way to fit the label showing only the most significant digits?

To better explain, I would like to have for example:
for `50000.45`: `50000`
for `4786.847`: `4786`
for `354.5342`: `354.5`
for `11.43566`: `11.43`
and for `0.014556`: `0.0145`

Possibly without having to do:

```py
if ... < variable < ...:
    round(variable,xx)
```

for all cases.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with tkinter. you're just asking how to convert a floating-point number to a fixed-width string.

Comment: You could use the logarithm with base 10 to find out how many decimals you need. If it is above 2, skip the decimals, if it is negative, add this number of decimals. You can format floats as decimals with the `.format()` method. (e.g. `"{0:.3f}".format(12345.12345)` results in `12345.123`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to convert a number into a set number of digits, you can convert the number into only decimals (aka `0 <= n <= 1`), then remove the last characters. You can do it like that:

```py
from math import log10

number = 123.456789
n_digits = 4

log = int(log10(number) + 1)
number /= 10**log # convert the number into only decimals

number = int(number*10**n_digits)/10**n_digits # keep the n first digits

number *= 10**log # multiply the number back
```

Or a more compact form:

```py
from math import log10

number = 123.456789
n_digits= 4

log = int(log10(number) + 1) - n_digits
number = int(number/10**log)*10**log
```

---

**[Edit]** You should use [Python `round()` function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp) in a simpler way:

```
number = round(number, n_digits-int(log10(number))-1)
```